# sed append after multi-line match

Tags: file, sed, patch

I got some code which looks like this:

```
lots of code... 
start(){
  some code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
  some code...
}
lots of code...
```

I would now like to insert some new code after `if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then` using `sed`. 
Since `if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then` exists multiple times, i cannot simply append the new code after each match. It should only be inserted after the first occurence inside of `start() { }`

Is it a good idea to use `sed` for this? Or what is the appropiate tool to perform such changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you need to start tracking state (for example, where am I in the file?  what have I seen so far?), I usually switch from sed to perl.  Here's a simple one-liner to do what you need (replace "NEW CODE" with the new code you need to insert; replace `<filename>` with the actual file):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$state=0} print; if (/^\s*start\(\){/) {$state++;} if (/if mountpart "\$1" \/mnt -w ; then/) { if ($state==1) {print "NEW CODE\n"; $state++;} }'  <filename>
```

Breaking that down briefly:  `-n` makes perl work a bit like sed; it will read each line and process it, however, it won't print the line unless you ask it to; this lets us output each line before we (possibly) output the new code.  `-e` makes perl read the program from the command line.  Taking the program and reformatting it, and adding comments, we get this:

```
// -n runs the program for every line of input
// but a BEGIN {} block only runs once, before input
BEGIN {
  //where are we in the input?
  // 0=no start() yet
  // 1=start() was seen
  // 2=we have output the new code; never do it again
  $state=0
} 

print;  // print the line we just read in, unchanged

if (/^\s*start\(\){/) {  //regex.  Did we see start(){ ?
  $state++;              //if so, change to next state
}

if (/if mountpart "\$1" \/mnt -w ; then/) {   //regex. did we see mountpart cmd?
  if ($state==1) {                            //if so, are we in the right state
    print "NEW CODE\n";                       //if so, output the new code
    $state++;                                 //...and change to next state 
                                              //...so we don't output new code 2x
  } 
}
```

Note here that we never reference the line by name... we just say "print" to print the line, and the regexes look like sed paterns, we assume we are matching against the line.  That's because `-n` reads each line into perl's `$_` variable, which is the default argument to functions like print.  This isn't how I would write a large perl program, but is appropriate (and idiomatic) for a one liner or brief one-off fix-up script like this.

You can also omit the `<filename>` and stream the input just like sed, e.g.,:

```
cat myfile.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN...'
```

Answer (score 1):

My sed script, patch.sed:

```
# replace your "if then" block inside start() by another pattern 
# to make it unrecognizable to sed in the next command
/^start(){/,/^}/!{s/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/outside_start/g}

# inside start(), append "NEW CODE" after "if then" block
/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/a\
NEW CODE

# recover your "if then" block outside start()
/^start(){/,/^}/!{s/outside_start/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/g}
```

input:

```
lots of code... 
if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
lots of code

start(){
  some code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
  some code...
}
lots of code...
if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
```

run it:

```
sed -f patch.sed input
```

output:

```
lots of code...
if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
lots of code

start(){
  some code...
if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
    NEW CODE
some code...
}
lots of code...
if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
```

Your "start(){" should be in the beginning of one line and so does the "}" matches with it. That's the way to match inside your start();

Without script, you can use "-e" options to execute mutiply edits by sed. But be careful to escape $.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^start()/,/^}/!b;x;/./{x;b};x;/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/!b;h;a\  NEWCODE' file
```

If there is a lot of `NEWCODE`, place it in a file and run this instead:

```
sed '/^start()/,/^}/!b;x;/./{x;b};x;/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/!b;h;r newcode.txt' file
```

Explanation:

The hold space is spare register. It can be used to manipulate text or (as in this case) as flag/switch to show an event has already happened.

- If the text is not between `start()` and `}` bail out `/^start()/,/^}/!b`
- Check the hold space and if there is anything in it bail out `x;/./{x;b}`
- Check for the marker and if not bail out `x;/if mountpart "$1" \/mnt -w ; then/!b`
- Place the marker string in the hold space as a state switch `h`
- Append/read the `NEWCODE` `a\ NEWCODE` or `r newcode.txt`

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@(collect)
@prolog
@(until)
start(){
@(end)
@(collect)
@inner
@(until)
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
@(end)
@(collect)
@epilog
@(end)
@(output)
@{prolog "\n"}
@{inner "\n"}
@{epilog[0]}
NEW TEXT
@{epilog[1..t] "\n"}
@(end)
```

Data:

```
lots of code... 
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
lots of code

start(){
  some code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
  some code...
}
lots of code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
```

Run:

```
$ txr insert.txr code.sh
lots of code... 
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
lots of code

start(){
  some code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
NEW TEXT
  some code...
}
lots of code...
  if mountpart "$1" /mnt -w ; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer.
Since txr is not available in most systems it is sadly not suitable for me.

Comment: It's been only ported only to Linux, Windows ("native" and Cygwin), OS/X, FreeBSD and NetBSD. Haven't heard from any Solaris users, etc.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean available but installed.